# Give an example of an infinite compact set $A$ such that its supremum is not a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, compactness

I got this one on a quiz the other day (We're only working in the reals). My solution was

$$A=[0,1]\cup\{3\}$$

The closed interval has the infinite points, and $\sup A=3$ is not a limit-point since each neighborhood of $3$ contains only the point $3$.

I was marked wrong but I can't figure out why.  Also let me know if there's any issues with my posting-- it's my first on here. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I can’t either: assuming that you’ve reproduced the question correctly, your answer is correct.

Comment: I agree with @BrianM.Scott (and hence with you). But it is false that *each* neighbourhood of $3$ contains only the point $3$ :)

Comment: Why $3$? Wouldn't $2$ be nicer?

Comment: It might be that somewhere the word "countable" was lost. Then your example doesn't meet that requirement. Anyway, you'll have to ask the grader why your solution was deemed incorrect. And it would be very interesting to know their reason, so if you find out, please let us know.

Comment: Where you wrote "The closed interval has the infinite points", did you mean the closed interval has _infinitely many_ points?  As written, one could wonder what an "infinite point" is in this context. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The original question stated "has infinite points." Nothing about uncountable/countable. I did not know there was such a thing as an infinite point, but I'm intrigued now!

Comment: Have you been given an example of correct answer?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I have not but I will ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is
$$\{0\}\cup\biggl\{\frac1n: n\in\mathbb N\biggr\}$$
Maybe that was expected?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, your answer appears correct, but I wonder what I would think if I saw all of what you wrote.  You say each neighborhood of $3$ contains only $3$, and that's wrong: There is in fact only *one* open neighborhood of $3$ that contains only that point, and that neighborhood is $\{3\}$.  The set $(1/2 - 1/100,1/2)\cup\{3\}$ is another open neighborhood of $3$, and it does not contain only that point.

Comment: The question given did not ask for an explanation, so I simply wrote the set down. I'll ask my prof. about it on Monday, probably just a simple oversight. 

It's good to know that the only open neighborhood of 3 in $\{3\}$ is $\{3\}$.